# Get closest unknown id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get something easy, but can't make it work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
    <p>
        Super <i>cool</i>
    </p>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="test">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Super <i>cool</i></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My idea is quite simple: click on `<i>` tag `console.log` the parent id. As you see sometime it's the direct parent, sometime it can be a parent from 13 nodes above.

I was looking something with `closest()` or `parents()` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're attempting to get the closest parent element that has an `id` attribute you can use `closest()` with the attribute selector:

```js
$('i').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('[id]').prop('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test-01">
  <p>
    Super <i>cool</i>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="test-02">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Super <i>cool</i></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

> I was looking something with `closest()` or `parents()` maybe ?

You were on the right track. If the `i` won't have an `id`, then:

```
var test = $(this).closest("[id]");
```

...which says, find me the closest element (starting with `this`) that has an `id` attribute.

If the `i` may have an `id` (you haven't shown one) and you don't want it, then you probably want

```
var test = $(this).parents("[id]").first();
```

or

```
var test = $(this).parent().closest("[id]");
```

Comment: Your solution works too ! Specially the first one. Thanks you :)